# Paired study designs for continuous data vs other types of data

Tags: interpretation, continuous-data, paired-data

My teacher says :

> We're going to consider something called a paired design. But for now,
> we'll only consider this when we're doing continuous outcomes.
> Sometimes you'll see this in the literature, but we'll also talk about
> the issues with regards to substantive interpretation of the results
> from such a design, there's some potential issues. So, it's not used
> all that often but it's an excellent launching point for the ideas.

Are paired designs most commonly used in the case of continuous outcomes? Why can paired designs for binary or time-to event data can have some potential issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are discussing the most simple of paired tests, such as the comparison of body weight before & after treatment across two groups in a paired t-test. The general use of paired data (i.e. repeated measures) is quite common & powerful where it is possible, though there are indeed things you need to keep in mind.

To be clear, I think your teacher means that there's potential issues with **any** paired design. Continuous data are simply quite common, because that's a very flexible and sensitive outcome.

Let's tackle the continuous case first: paired data are really about the *difference* between two measurements, such as before & after treatment in one subject. It's important to keep in mind that such observations are correlated; the post-treatment measurement will likely be closer to the pre-treatment value *in that subject* than compared to another random observation from your population. This increases your power as the variance will be lower. You have to account for that correlation however, because your observations aren't all independent anymore. A paired t-test handles this correlation by treating our pre-post difference within a subject as a single measurement.

The big drawback of doing so is that you've essentially discarded the absolute scale of these measurements: sure, a subject might have changed by -2 kg, but was that from 40 to 38 or from 110 to 108? That absolute value may also be informative/prognostic -- it's usually easier for people with larger weight to also lose larger amounts of it. The first extension you'd usually make to a paired t-test is therefore to include that absolute value somewhere again as a covariate in a linear model/analysis of (co)variance. A next step might be to include multiple correlated post-treatment measurements in a repeated measures model.

The binary and time-to-event cases are not that different from the above, the issue is more that such differences are either less informative or difficult if not impossible to determine. For example, a time-to-event on mortality or some relative improvement after treatment initiation can only be observed once. For binary outcomes you tend to try and start a randomized experiment with everyone in a similar state, and even if you had a meaningful pre-treatment measurement there's only four possible pre/post combinations, so you gain much less granular information than in the continuous case.

It *is* still possible & more powerful to have repeated measures post-treatment using such data types in many cases though. You would again have to take into account the correlation structure or dependence between observations in your analysis (e.g. recurrent events, binomial GLMM).